# JPA with Hibernate: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager error

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm trying to setup a project using JPA with Hibernate.

My **persistence.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="Application">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webshop" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

These are the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And the project structure:

[image]

When I try to get the entity manager I get this error:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Application

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Application");
```

Comment: You should be using `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` rather than `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be having <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have the same issues. I trie to change the ``org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence`` to ``org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`` but don't work too

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Naros said: For Hibernate 5.2.2 you should use:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

instead of:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```